# Insertar hexadecimal en int con cin

Tags: c++

He estado tratando de solucionar el siguiente ejercicio:

> Escriba un programa para evaluar la introducción de valores enteros en los formatos decimal, octal y hexadecimal. Imprima cada entero leído por el programa en los tres formatos. Evalúe el programa con los siguientes datos de entrada: 10, 010, 0x10.

El problema que tengo es con la entrada del valor hexadecimal de la forma `0x10`. Utilizando `cin` solo se almacena el cero inicial, pero se pierde el resto de la cadena. Voy a explicarlo con un código:

```
int main()
    {
        int valor;
        cin >> valor; //  entrada 0x10
        cout << valor; // salida: 0 -> se pierde "x10"
    }
```

Me han recomendado utilizar un **arreglo de caracteres** para almacenar la entrada de `cin`.  Además, hay que tener en cuenta que el programa no sabe de antemano el tipo de valor que el usuario introduce, es decir, no sabe si el usuario introducirá un octal, un decimal, o un hexadecimal.

- ¿Cómo se puede lograr esto?
- ¿Algún otro método para resolver el problema?

---

Nota: No son válidos los métodos para c++ 11.

Answer (score 3):

Mucho cuidado con esto:

> Evalúe el programa con los siguientes datos de entrada: 10, 010, 0x10.

- 10<sub>10</sub> es 10<sub>10</sub>.
- 10<sub>8</sub> es 8<sub>10</sub>, la base octal se representa anteponiendo un cero al literal numérico: `010`.
- 10<sub>16</sub> es 16<sub>10</sub>, la base hexadecimal se representa anteponiendo `0x` al literal numérico: `0x10`.

Para que la consola te lea números en octal o hexadecimal, debes decirle que pretendes hacer tal cosa, de lo contrario asumirá base decimal:

```
std::cin >> std::oct >> valor;
//          ^^^^^^^^ <-- Vamos a leer un número en octal.
std::cin >> std::hex >> valor;
//          ^^^^^^^^ <-- Vamos a leer un número en hexadecimal.
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jYu/CsIwEIfn3lMcOFQHIY42IU/iEtIgB80lpNcupc8eSUXQze37/fl8zten97WeiP20jAENpVlKcNHCdxcdU7YAxILREZ8vsEHX0uqmVLZdA0A3yzgMnhitxYOTl8bHR3/2tAga8y4b9A/u9a/8l1CCLIVRadhrVTcF9xc).

Ve con cuidado con las opciones de lectura, ¡porque son pegajosas! si usas `std::oct` o `std::hex`, las siguientes lecturas se considerarán octales o hexadecimales.

Comment: Entiendo la respuesta, pero la idea es que el programa no sepa que tipo de valor va a recibir.

Comment: No sabes que tipo de valor va a recibir, pero sabes qué formato sigue cada tipo de valor que recibes 

Comment: En el código que propusiste se asume que los valores a introducir son de formato octal. La idea del programa es que determine cuál es la base que el usuario introduce, y muestre los equivalentes de las demás bases. Por esto propone los datos de entrada 10, 010, 0x10 (los cuales corresponden a diferentes formatos)

Comment: Lo se @Beats2019 pero no te voy a hacer el ejercicio. Tienes todas las pistas para, con la *ayuda* que te he facilitado, llegues por tu cuenta a la solución.

Answer (score 1):

El comportamiento que detallas:

```
int valor;
cin >> valor; //  entrada 0x10
cout << valor; // salida: 0 -> se pierde "x10"
```

Es el esperado. A `cin` le estás diciendo que te lea un entero, sin más, y los enteros por defecto (que son los que se encuentran en base 10), **no tienen caracteres** tipo `x`, por lo que al encontrarse ese caracter simplemente deja de leer.

Como te están pidiendo que interpretes la entrada del usuario, lo más sencillo es leer una cadena de caracteres. Seguidamente analizas dicha cadena para saber cómo interpretar la secuencia que ha introducido el usuario:

```
std::string cadena;
std::cin >> cadena; // entrada 0x10

if( cadena[0] == '0' )
{
  if( cadena[1] == 'x' )
  {
    // El número es hexadecimal
  }
  else
  {
    // El número es octal
  }
}
else
{
  // El número es decimal
}
```

Comment: Sí! Pero no encuentro la manera de imprimir en los demás formatos

Comment: @Beats2019 Para imprimir ya tienes la otra respuesta